# Does SCOPEIDENTITY() works for integer value only?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am using sql server 2008 in which i have written a stored procedure, which insert some values in the table and then give back those inserted values. I am using `nvarchar` as primary key. So in order to select last inserted values, i am using `scopeidentity()` function but the problem is that it is inserting the values but not giving back the last inserted values. The code is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cms_AddOwnerSession
@sessionId nvarchar(max),
@ownerId int,
@ownerName nvarchar(50),
@username nvarchar(30),
@password nvarchar(30)

AS
BEGIN

IF(@sessionId <> NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO OwnerSession
        (SessionId,
        OwnerId,
        OwnerName,
        Username,
        [Password])
        VALUES
        (@sessionId,
        @ownerId,
        @ownerName,
        @username,
        @password)
        SET @sessionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
    SELECT
        ISNULL (SessionId,'NULL')   'sessionId',
        ISNULL (OwnerId,0)          'ownerId',
        ISNULL (OwnerName,'')       'ownerName',
        ISNULL (Username,'')        'username',
        ISNULL ([Password],'')      'password' 
    FROM OwnerSession
    WHERE SessionId = @sessionId
END
GO
```

Comment: What is the PK on your table?

Answer (score 2):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last generated `IDENTITY` column value. It has nothing to do with the data that you yourself provide. It does not match the first column and it does not match the first column that has "ID" in its name. (I think one of those is the misunderstanding here).

Comment: So, i think i need to give another auto-increamented column in this, in order to use this function.

Comment: I don't this statement `SET @sessionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. `@sessionId` already contains a valid value, doesn't it? With what do you want to overwrite it? It seems you don't need to do anything here.

Comment: Yes, you are right by the way. But still i wanted to know that for some other reason, now i understand. Is there any function in sql which returns last inserted primary key?

Comment: @user2575061 There isn't, [for a reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906970/does-scopeidentity-works-for-integer-value-only#comment26158071_17907096). If you still want it, you can use the [output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[scope_identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) returns last [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) value generated IN YOUR SCOPE. Your `SessionId` is not an identity.
Be very careful with [scope_identity(), @@identity and IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) values:

> @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY, and IDENT_CURRENT are similar functions
>   because they all return the last value inserted into the IDENTITY
>   column of a table.
>
> @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated
>   in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns
>   the value only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to
>   a specific scope.
>
> IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a
>   specified table.   IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value generated
>   for a specific table in any session and any scope.

Comment: is there any function which return last inserted primary key?

Comment: not that I know of. But in your query, you inserted all the values into your table, so you have all values already, isn't it?

Comment: @user2575061 There isn't because you don't need it. If your primary key is auto-generated, then it's an `int` and you can use `scope_indentity`. If it's not auto-generated, then you already know the key, because you have to know it prior to inserting.

Answer (score 1):

In your context `scope_identity()` would not work even if you had used an `IDENTITY` column because you are trying to access the value outside of the scope of the procedure that inserted the row. To reliably get the value that was inserted within a procedure you need to record it within that same statement or at least the same procedure in case `IDENTITY` values are used.

In your case you can either grab the supplied value and return it to the caller, or you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to do that.

An introduction to the different `IDENTITY` related functions and the shortfalls can be found here: http://sqlity.net/en/351/identity-crisis/

That article also shows how the `OUTPUT` clause can be used to deal with all those shortfalls.

But always remember, if the insert finished and you did not capture the value during its execution, there is no guarantee that you will get the correct value afterwards - independent of the method used.